# How to set width for columns in div table?

Tags: html, jquery, css

After adding a row, there was a problem with setting the columns width. If run a snippet, very clearly visible that the cell sizes do not match the specified values.

How to set the width for columns in the case below?

```css
.divTable{
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
}
.divTableRow {
 display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
 border: 1px solid #999999;
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 3px 10px;
 

}
.divTableHeading {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-header-group;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableFoot {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-footer-group;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
 display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
<div class="divTableBody">
<div class="divTableRow">

<div class="divTableCell" style="width:10%">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell" style="width:40%">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell" style="width:50%">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div class="divTableRow" >texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttextte xttexttexttexttexttexttextt exttexttexttexttextt xttexttexttexttexttexttex ttexttext</div>
<div class="divTableRow">

<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please can you add more detail to explain **explicitly** what it is, you are asking?

Comment: If you want to use `display:table;` then why don't you use table itself than using `div`?

Comment: to Manjuboyz: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: to Equinox: I fix my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider `table-layout: fixed;`

```css
.divTable {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
}

.divTableCell,
.divTableHead {
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTableFoot {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-footer-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">

      <div class="divTableCell" style="width:10%">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell" style="width:40%">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell" style="width:50%">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>

    <div class="divTableRow">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttextte xttexttexttexttexttexttextt exttexttexttexttextt xttexttexttexttexttexttex ttexttext</div>
    <div class="divTableRow">

      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the table have to be made of divs?

If not, use the HTML `<table>` tag and set it's width explicitly as well as it's display property.

Then you can set the width of the columns:

https://codepen.io/daniel-knights/pen/KKdgYzW

Comment: I'm going to use slideToggle() for a div with text, so just a table isn't appropriate for this case.

Answer (score 0):

[Your modified code]

//Hello,
//you should try this

//I forgot that there exists a property max-width,

```
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  display: table-cell;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 120px!important;
```

this will definately work

Comment: Also you have to copy paste the 1st or 2nd html code of divTableRow to 3rd one.

Comment: It didn't help me.

Comment: You want to apply same width to cells?Then above edited code will work.